# Creating grid of DIVs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a grid of DIVs (all DIVs will have same dimensions) and set them a defined names, colors, positions etc. Which is the most relevant/easiest/fastest method of doing this according to you?

Any answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

An iterator (for loop would work) that uses the append method to add a bunch of divs.

If each one has slight differences, track the differences in a map or something the iterator can also access.

Comment: Jai actually took the time to provide some code; feel free to upvote and accept his answer (if it works for you!) instead. ;)

Answer (score 2):

No doubt iterator in javascript like most used and most favorite `for(){}` loop is fine and in terms of jQuery `.each()` is what you are looking for.

using for loop with jQuery:

```
for(var i = 0; i<=10; i++){
   $('<div />').addClass('sameDiv').attr('id','div'+i).appendTo('body');
}
```

#### [CHECK THIS OUT](http://jsfiddle.net/UNCMY/)

Comment: Ayup. Updated the fiddle with a "properties in an array" proof of concept. You could use something like an array of objects full of properties if you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/UNCMY/3/

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct, but I prefer the jQuery element creation syntax:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'sameDiv',
        'id'    : 'div' + i
    }).appendTo('body');
}
```

> **Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K5ERR/**